# how can i use Django with html CSS JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am making a website and through some sources. I find out that Django is for backend and html CSS and JS is for front end.

So I am designing my pages in the later 3 and not started developing the backend.

*Is there any way that I can use Django with html CSS and JS?* (please suggest an easy method as I am a newbie ,however I am quite familiar with python )

Comment: you want to use html ,css and javascript in django ?

Answer (score 0):

Django would be used to match urls with pages. Specifically you would need to create a view that renders a template (here comes the html) and some static files (css, js). If you wont use a database i would suggest that you use flask which does the thing is described above much more easily.